# Calculate/plot mean square displacement for single particle in 3d from data in excel file

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate and plot the mean square displacement (MSD) of a single particle in 3d in python. In my excel file, I have values in separate columns for x, y, and z in rows 2-29. How do I calculate MSD?

I initially tried the code I have listed below up until the line "MSD = np.mean(diff_sq)," but when I tried to plot the MSD against time, I was shown an error saying that the first dimensions were not the same. This is because MSD is outputting a single value instead of some type of array and therefore the two cannot be plotted together.

```
xdata = xl['x '][0:27]
ydata = xl['y'][0:27]
zdata = xl['z'][0:27]

import numpy as np
r = (xdata**2 + ydata**2+zdata**2)**0.5
diff = np.diff(r) 
diff_sq = diff**2
MSD = np.mean(diff_sq)
for i in range(28):
```

I need to calculate the MSD in increments, so I was trying to write a for loop to help with that. I got stuck in my for loop, however, because I am not quite sure how to write the for loop for my data in the excel file.

Comment: Okay, so you want to calculate MSD for each of the 27 coordinates, is that correct? So you would end up with an array or list of 27 MSDs?

Comment: The line `MSD = np.mean(diff_sq) ` is calculating the mean of the array with 27 elements, so it is returning a single mean as the result. That might cause the problem for you

Comment: @Ahndwoo yes, that's correct. Then, once I have a list/array of 27 MSDs I can plot it with the 27 values I have for time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of MSDs using list comprehension. We'll create a list of the mean of a progressively larger slice of `diff`. So the first entry will be the mean of the first list item, the second entry will be the mean of the first two list items, etc.

```
xdata = xl['x'][0:28]
ydata = xl['y'][0:28]
zdata = xl['z'][0:28]

import numpy as np
r = (xdata**2 + ydata**2+zdata**2)**0.5
diff = np.diff(r) 
diff_sq = diff**2
MSD = [np.mean(diff_sq[0:i]) for i in range(1, 29)]
```

Also note: I changed the slice indices from `[0:27]` to `[0:28]`, since it will exclude the last index. To get the first 27 items from a list, you need to slice at length+1.

Comment: Thank you! I am now seeing a plot, but it is not giving me the correlation I want. I checked over my data, but the code makes sense and should be producing a linear correlation (when the axis limits are adjusted). Do you have any suggestions on how to go about my problem?

Comment: It looks like the graph of an inverse function instead of something like a logarithmic graph (or, something with a horizontal asymptotes).